# Country Currency formatting using 'NumberFormat' class Java

Tags: java, class, printing, currency, currency-formatting

I'm currently working on a task that involves taking a double-precision number representing a sum of money and using the NumberFormat class' getCurrencyInstance method to convert it into the currency formats of US, India, China, and France.

Input:

```
A single double-precision number denoting 'payment'
```

Output:

```
On the first line, print US: 'u' where 'u' is 'payment' formatted for US currency.
On the second line, print India: 'i' where 'i' is 'payment' formatted for the Indian currency.
On the third line, print China: 'c' where 'c' is 'payment' formatted for Chinese currency.
On the fourth line, print France: 'f' where 'f' is formatted for French currency.
```

Sample input:

```
12324.134
```

Sample output:

```
US: $12,324.13

India: Rs.12,324.13

China: ￥12,324.13

France: 12 324,13 €
```

My code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.Currency;

public class Solution {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        double payment = scanner.nextDouble();
        scanner.close();
        
        Locale indiaLocale = new Locale("en", "IN");
        
        Locale locale = Locale.US;
        Currency us = Currency.getInstance(locale);
        String symbol = us.getSymbol(locale);
        System.out.println("US: " + symbol + payment);
        
        Locale locale2 = indiaLocale;
        Currency in = Currency.getInstance(locale2);
        String symbol2 = in.getSymbol(locale2);
        System.out.println("India: " + symbol2 + payment);
        
        Locale locale3 = Locale.CHINA;
        Currency ch = Currency.getInstance(locale3);
        String symbol3 = ch.getSymbol(locale3);
        System.out.println("China: " + symbol3 + payment);
        
        Locale locale4 = Locale.FRANCE;
        Currency fr = Currency.getInstance(locale4);
        String symbol4 = fr.getSymbol(locale4);
        System.out.println("France: " + payment + " " + symbol4);
    }
}
```

My input:

```
12324.134
```

My output:

```
US: $12324.134

India: Rs.12324.134

China: ￥12324.134

France: 12324.134 €
```

My problem lies in the format of the input, '12324.134'. As you can see, I've managed to output the right currency symbols, especially India as India does not have a built-in Locale, so I had to construct one where the language is en (i.e., English).

I just can't seem to get the commas in the right place and for some reason, France's expected output has a space after the first 2 digits. It might be because I haven't used the right methods of the Currency class but this is where Im stuck at. Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: This example does it differently but could be some clues here: http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-use-numberformat-to-format-currencies.html#:~:text=To%20format%20a%20number%20according,currency%20of%20the%20default%20locale.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, using floating point numbers for currency values will eventually hit a representation error. Better use BigDecimal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance`

You probably should use [`NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance(java.util.Locale)) and `NumberFormat.format`. Try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double payment = 12324.134; // I'd use BigDecimal instead of double here, BTW. See the comment from another user under your post.

    Locale us = Locale.US;
    System.out.println("US: " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(us).format(payment));

    Locale india = new Locale("en", "IN");
    System.out.println("India: " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(india).format(payment));

    Locale china = Locale.CHINA;
    System.out.println("China: " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(china).format(payment));

    Locale france = Locale.FRANCE;
    System.out.println("France: " + NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(france).format(payment));
}
```

The output is:

```
US: $12,324.13
India: ₹12,324.13
China: ¥12,324.13
France: 12 324,13 €
```

It is even said in your task:

> using the NumberFormat class' getCurrencyInstance method

Comment: You are correct that NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance should be used.  It should also be noted that the Currency class is not needed here at all, so all of the Currency.getInstance lines and all of the getSymbol lines can be removed from the code.

Comment: @VGR Totally agree, I've cleaned the code.

Answer (score 1):

> *"... I'm currently working on a task that involves taking a double-precision number representing a sum of money and using the NumberFormat class' getCurrencyInstance method to convert it into the currency formats of US, India, China, and France. ..."*

In you're example you are using *[Currency#getInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Currency.html#getInstance(java.util.Locale))* which is different than *[NumberFormat#getCurrencyInstance](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/text/NumberFormat.html#getCurrencyInstance(java.util.Locale))*.

And, you should consider switching to the *[BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html)* class, as recommended by *Java*.

*[Primitive Data Types (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language > Language Basics)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)*.

> *"... **float**: ... This data type should never be used for precise values, such as currency. For that, you will need to use the
> [java.math.BigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html) class instead.
> [Numbers and Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/index.html) covers BigDecimal and other useful classes provided by the Java platform. ..."*

The recommendation is to use a "half-even" rounding-mode, as specified by the *[RoundingMode#HALF_EVEN](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/math/RoundingMode.html#HALF_EVEN)* *JavaDoc*.

> *"... **API Note**:
>
> This is the rounding mode that statistically minimizes cumulative error when applied repeatedly over a sequence of calculations. It is sometimes known as "Banker's rounding," and is chiefly used in the USA. This rounding mode is analogous to the rounding policy used for most float and double arithmetic operators in Java (JLS [15.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se20/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.4)). This mode corresponds to the IEEE 754 rounding-direction attribute roundTiesToEven. ..."*

The *[Scanner](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html)* class also conveniently provides a *[nextBigDecimal](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextBigDecimal())* method.

```java
BigDecimal payment = scanner.nextBigDecimal().setScale(2, HALF_EVEN);
```

Output

```
12324.134
US: $12324.13
India: ₹12324.13
China: ¥12324.13
France: 12324.13 €
```

> *"... My problem lies in the format of the input, '12324.134'. ...*
>
> *... I just can't seem to get the commas in the right place and for some reason, France's expected output has a space after the first 2 digits. It might be because I haven't used the right methods of the Currency class but this is where Im stuck at. Any advice is appreciated."*

Here is a relevant *Java* tutorial on *"Customizing Formats"*.
*[Customizing Formats (The Java™ Tutorials > Internationalization > Formatting)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/decimalFormat.html)*.

And, here is a re-factor.

Note that `Currency.getInstance(Locale.CHINA).getSymbol()` returns a different symbol than the *format* method, `CN¥` over `¥`.

```java
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
BigDecimal payment = scanner.nextBigDecimal().setScale(2, HALF_EVEN);
scanner.close();
DecimalFormat df;
for (Locale locale : List.of(US, new Locale("en", "IN"), CHINA, FRANCE)) {
    df = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(locale);
    System.out.printf("%s: %s%n", locale.toString(), df.format(payment));
}
```

Output

```
12324.134
en_US: $12,324.13
en_IN: ₹12,324.13
zh_CN: ¥12,324.13
fr_FR: 12 324,13 €
```